# Multiple count plots in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a CSV file which has multiple columns, now I am trying to plot side by side count plot for selected columns, using below code, I am able to make only two-column, but when I trying to add more column, it's not working. How to plot multiple selected columns and plot it side by side. 
While I plotting two graphs, its overlapping, how to increase the gap.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

train_data = pd.read_csv(r"train_ctrUa4K.csv")

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.countplot(train_data['Gender'], ax=ax[0])
sns.countplot(train_data['Dependents'], ax=ax[1])
#sns.countplot(train_data['Self_Employed'], ax=ax[1])
#sns.countplot(train_data['Property_Area'], ax=ax[1,1])

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the number of columns in the call to [`subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4)
sns.countplot(train_data['Gender'], ax=ax[0])
sns.countplot(train_data['Dependents'], ax=ax[1])
sns.countplot(train_data['Self_Employed'], ax=ax[2])
sns.countplot(train_data['Property_Area'], ax=ax[3])
```

If you have too many subplots to fit on a single line, you can increase the number of rows as well. Be careful that if you have more than one row and more than one column, then the variable `ax` will be a 2D array:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
sns.countplot(train_data['Gender'], ax=ax[0,0])
sns.countplot(train_data['Dependents'], ax=ax[0,1])
sns.countplot(train_data['Self_Employed'], ax=ax[1,0])
sns.countplot(train_data['Property_Area'], ax=ax[1,1])
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine, But plots get overlaps. Please can you tell, how to control the size and increase the gap between plots?

Comment: Call plt.tight_layout() at the end